# How to keep display one Hover at a time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a small hover script and it works like that: 
When i hover on a link it is fade the relevant div.

Now, i tried to create a second link and configure it to display the second div and i have succeeded, but, when i hover them **fast** one-after-one it display **BOTH faded Divs** and stay stuck a while (with 2 divs display instead of 1) until the first div returns.

I want to display only **one** div at a time when i hover even if i hover fast between links.

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>

<style>
#bank {display:none;}
</style>

<div><a href="#" id="btn">Show bank div and hide fancy div</a></div>
<div><a href="#" id="btn-bk">Show back and hid fancy div</a></div><br>
<div id="bank">Bank Div</div>
<div id="fancy">Fancy Div</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

$(window).load(function(){
$('#btn').hover(function(e){    
    $('#fancy').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('#bank').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});


$('#btn-bk').hover(function(e){    
    $('#bank').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('#fancy').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
/]]> 
</script>
```

See it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/rami7250/1jLtxdr7/

Comment: Check [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1jLtxdr7/6/). You can use `stop(true, true)`.

Comment: YEAP! You solve this! Please insert your answer so i can vote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this prevent 2 div shown at the same time

```js
$('#btn').hover(function(e){
    $('#fancy').stop().hide();
    $('#bank').fadeIn('slow');
}); 
$('#btn-bk').hover(function(e){    
    $('#bank').stop().hide();
    $('#fancy').fadeIn('slow');    
});
```

```css
#bank {display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><a href="#" id="btn">Show bank div and hide fancy div</a></div>
<div><a href="#" id="btn-bk">Show back and hid fancy div</a></div><br>
<div id="bank">Bank Div</div>
<div id="fancy">Fancy Div</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#btn').hover(function(e){    
    $('#fancy').stop(true, true).fadeOut('slow', function(){
        //--------^ Add 'stop(true, true)'
        $('#bank').fadeIn('slow');
    });
}); 
$('#btn-bk').hover(function(e){    
    $('#bank').stop(true, true).fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('#fancy').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

By adding `stop(true, true)` you can start current animation immediately and your previous animations will be removed from queue. [Read More](https://api.jquery.com/stop/)

[**Example Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/1jLtxdr7/6/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use a flag to return function if it's already running:

```
var flag;
$('#btn').hover(function(e){
if (flag)return;
flag = true;
    $('#fancy').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('#bank').fadeIn('slow');
        flag = false;
    });
});


$('#btn-bk').hover(function(e){  
if (flag)return;
flag = true;
    $('#bank').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('#fancy').fadeIn('slow');
         flag = false;
    });
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1jLtxdr7/1/)

Comment: It can be a good solution, but if i go and hover first on "Show back.." it is not display the second div.

Comment: the way I interpreted the question is that `$('#btn-bk').hover` is supposed to display `Fancy Div` , and nothing is noticeable because it's already displayed  ; what would you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

This is because if you hover over an animation while another is in progress it doesn't stop the current animation. You can force this to happen by using the stop() function for each call.

```
$('#btn').hover(function(e){    
    $('#fancy').stop().fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('#bank').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});


$('#btn-bk').hover(function(e){    
    $('#bank').stop().fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('#fancy').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

See my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1jLtxdr7/2/

Comment: Your fiddle has the same problem. It display both divs when hover fast between them. It also not display the second div if i hover first on the "Show back and hid fancy div".

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>

<style>
#bank {display:none;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div><a href="#" id="btn">Show bank div and hide fancy div</a></div>
<BR>
<BR>
<div><a href="#" id="btn-bk">Show back and hid fancy div</a></div><br>
<div id="bank">Bank Div</div>
<div id="fancy">Fancy Div</div>

<script type="text/javascript">


$(window).load(function(){
$('#btn').hover(function(e){    
    $('#fancy').fadeOut(40, function(){
        $('#bank').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});


$('#btn-bk').hover(function(e){    
    $('#bank').fadeOut(40, function(){
        $('#fancy').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
});
</script>
<body>
</html>
```

Try is one . you can give decimal numbers to fix speed of fadeIn function

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$('.toggle_text').hover(function(e){ 
    var text = $(this).attr("data-info");
    var text_to_show = $("#"+text).html();    
    
    $('#show_div').fadeOut('slow', function(){
      $('#show_div').html(text_to_show).fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

```css
#bank {display:none;}
.hide {display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><a href="#" id="btn" class="toggle_text" data-info="show_fancy">Show bank div and hide fancy div</a></div>
<div><a href="#" id="btn-bk" class="toggle_text" data-info="show_bank">Show back and hid fancy div</a></div><br>
<div id="show_bank" class="hide">Bank Div</div>
<div id="show_fancy" class="hide">Fancy Div</div>
<div id="show_div"></div>
```

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/1jLtxdr7/3/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try This one

```
$('#btn').hover(
    function(e){    
        $('#bank').show();
  },
  function(e){
    $('#fancy, #bank').hide();
  }
);


$('#btn-bk').hover(
    function(e){    
        $('#fancy').show();
  },
  function(e){
    $('#fancy, #bank').hide()
  }
);
```